# Routing for external react component/module

Tags: reactjs, react-router, components

I am building an external React component/module that has many sublevels/pages and routes. I am using React Router V4. This component will be imported into a host application that itself has it's own routing system. The host app is also using React Router V4.

The component's root view is a grid view of cards and when the user click one of the cards it brings them to a detail view of the card.  When the user is on a detail view, the url in the browser should change so that a user can bookmark the url of that page and visit that page later.

How should the routing work between the host application and the component? Should the host app pass in the route schema into the component or should the component and host app have it's own separate routing system. Does anyone have any examples of this?

Comment: Is the host application also using React Router V4?

Comment: yes, the host app is also using React Router v4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Router V4 plays very nicely in this situation.  Both apps would need their own top level Router component in order to be able to run standalone.  But you could organize the code so you can reuse the main switch statement for the SubModule.  The urls on the host application would all be prefixed with /subModule/, i.e. /subModule/foo, and they would just be /foo on the subModule standalone application.

```
HostApp.jsx
<Router>
<Switch>
 <Route path="/other" component={Other} />
 <Route path="/subModule" component={SubModuleRouter} />
</Switch>
</Router>

SubModule.jsx
<Router>
  <Route path="/" component={SubModuleRouter} />
</Router>

SubModuleRouter.jsx
<Switch>
 <Route exact path="/foo" component={FooComponent} />
</Switch>
```