# How to handle react routing for module?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, components, git-submodules

I am having react application with submodules.

Main App will have list of sub modules and where the submodule is a separate react application.

**Code:**

**submodule/app.js**

```
  <Switch>
     <Route exact path="/" component={Product} />
     <Route path="/productdetail/:id" component={ProductDetail} />
  </Switch>
```

**mainApp/app.js**

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
    <Route exact path="/product" component={Product} /> // Look at the below code of product.js
<Switch>
```

**mainApp/components/product.js**

```
 import { Product } from "product-module"; // No issues with import and it is fine.

 return ( 
  <div>
    <Product /> // The view is not rendering and I suspect there will be issue related with routing.
  </div>
)
```

So here submodule has different set of routes and after that we are generating it as module/library and including inside main app.

Installing the submodule inside the main app works fine but the view is not rendering and I think the issue is related with routing.

I have referred this question: [Routing for external react component/module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47912305/7785337) but it didn't helped me.

Could you please kindly help me what changes should I need to make in submodule or in main app to see the product module in main app?

Comment: You take reference of below link.
https://reactrouter.com/web/example/route-config